# gradle release plugin release-opinion

Tags: nexus, gradle-release-plugin

Im trying to use gradle [release plugin](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git/wiki/Release%20Plugins) to deploy my artifact on a private nexus repository but actually i face a problem during the upload archive fase.

the upload arrives to the end even if nexus answer with a 400 but inside the release repository i find every kind of release evene dev-* milestone-*

I would expect only rc-* or final release on release repository and dev-* and milestone-* on snapshot repository

actually my config is

```
plugins {
id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' version '1.7.0'
id 'org.ajoberstar.git-publish' version '0.2.0'

id 'org.ajoberstar.release-opinion' version '1.7.0'
}    apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'


group = 'social.picnik.backend'
//version = '3.31.3-SNAPSHOT'

description = " --backend-services-- "

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

tasks.release.dependsOn 'build', 'uploadArchives'


uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/releases") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/snapshots") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
        }
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '3.4'
}

dependencies 
......
```

the command i launch is

```
gradle release
```

but then i found in nexus release repository
this version

> 3.31.3-dev.22.uncommitted+c6e4922

i would have liked to see it in snapshot repository not in release

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
tasks.afterReleaseBuild.dependsOn uploadArchives
```

Should do the trick.